# Console template in Visual studio 2013 not there?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, console

So today I downloaded visual studio 2013 express twice (the download was canceled the first time) And when I opened it, it told me to get a windows 8 licence, and I did... The thing is, when I want to start a new project, the only template available are store app... Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DCQH.png

I am aware back in visual studio 2010, there was an option for console application and I wonder where it is... Maybe I am being stupid, but I do need help! I do not want to create windows 8 application :/.

Any help would be great!

Comment: You need Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. Probably you downloaded Express 2013 for Windows.

Answer (score 5):

You have most likely downloaded `VISUAL STUDIO 2013 EXPRESS FOR WINDOWS (STORE)`.

You need the edition for Windows Desktop, [located here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787). See all links and editions [in Scott Hanselman's recent blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadVisualStudioExpress.aspx).

Comment: Thanks you for the quick respond! I will once again download it for a third time :(. Thanks again!

Comment: @Marcel N. "**Desktop**" is correct AFAIK; however, your "located here" link, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787, is broken. ["__Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 with Update 4 for Windows Desktop__"](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop) is the current version; one can choose between "install now" and a .iso image.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the version that you require to create a console application is
"Express 2013 for Windows **Desktop**"

There are 3 versions of Visual Studio Express.

all three versions are found here:
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

["**Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 with Update 4 for Windows Desktop**"](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop) is the current version; one can choose between "install now" and a .iso image.